# Arbitrarily reorder and sort javascript array of object literals

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm

Good morning everyone!  I'm working through a problem this morning that entails reordering the following javascript array given the requirements I've crafted below:

EDIT: I realize "reorder" and "sort" are sometimes used interchangeably.  But in this context, I'm referring to 'reorder' as changing the 'order' property such that all objects have a unique order. Sorting just refers to keeping the array in ascending order based on the order property.

```
var toOrder = [
  {
    order: 1,
    visible: true
  },
  {
    order: 2,
    visible: true
  }
]
```

1. Client code must be able to re-order this array, given a function that takes the object and a new order.
2. Array must stay sorted in ascending order (by the order property) at all times
3. No two objects can have the same order

I wrote some code that gets the job done, but I'm searching for a more eloquent solution.  My current algorithm for reorder (in psudocode) looks like this:

```
reorder(myObject, newOrder);
```

1. Loop over toOrder array
2. When matched object is found:
3. If new order is less than starting order
4. Increment order property for objects between new order and starting order
5. If new order is greater than starting order
6. Decrement order property between starting order and new order
7. If new order is the same as old order, do nothing
8. Set new order on matched object
9. sort()

The utility method "sort()" uses the native javascript sort() function to assure the array is ordered by the 'order' property at all times.  This works fine, but is there some more efficient/eloquent solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not JSON. You're using JavaScript Array-literal syntax within a JavaScript program. Its syntax is similar in appearance to JSON, but in your context, it's just JavaScript. ...not to mention that the object syntax wouldn't even be considered JSON when taken out of the context of the program.

Comment: *"I wrote some code that gets the job done, but I'm searching for a more eloquent solution."* Where's that code? How can we know if our solutions are any better than yours?

Comment: I wrote out the exact psudocode above, and I'm looking for a psudocode solution (in the context of javascript) /thumbsdown

Comment: @user2736012 a technicality... but thanks, I made the edit.  I hear them used interchangeably by developers day in and day out.

Comment: @ThinkingInBits I wouldn't feel too bad about misusing it: even Google has [erroneously used "JSON object" in their official documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#attr-callback).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your wording is a bit confusing, but here's how I'm interpreting it:

You have an array of objects, each with an order property. This order property must be unique.
You wish to take Object A and place it in a new position, and re-apply the order properties so they are unique and sequential.

Here's how I would do it:

```
function reorder(object, newIndex) {

    var oldIndex = toOrder.indexOf(object);
    toOrder.splice(oldIndex, 1);
    toOrder.splice(newIndex, 0, object);

    // If you can guarantee your order properties were already indexed,
    // this loop could instead be
    // for (var i = Math.min(oldIndex, newIndex); i <= Math.max(oldIndex, newIndex); ++i)
    for (var i = 0; i < toOrder.length; ++i) {
        toOrder[i].order = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1! You might even optimise the loop to go from `min(newIndex, oldIndex)` to `max(newIndex, oldIndex)`

Comment: Very nice guys.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Bergi Good idea. I'll make that change

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler solution (still works for arbitrary `order` values, not only where `newOrder` is the actual array index):

1. Set `myObject.order` to `newOrder` (where newOrder is some number between orders at the aim position). E.g `-1` to move in front, or `1.5` to move between `#1` and `#2`
2. Use the custom sort()
3. loop over the `toOrder` array and set the `order` of each item to its index (so that it becomes an integer again or is increased/decreased to match the new position)